# What parts of ASP.NET does Azure Functions use?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Azure Functions uses the `HttpResult` and `IActionResult` classes from ASP.NET (Core?) to handle HTTP triggers. What version of ASP.NET is this for the Azure Functions v2 Runtime? I know that v2 uses .NET Standard 2.0 running on .NET Core, so I'm assuming ASP.NET Core is used, but which version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two concepts, one is the host/runtime that powers Azure Functions.

Right now, Azure Function 2.0 runtime is based on [.Net Core 2.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobs.Script.WebHost.csproj#L4), and references [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App v2.1.6](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/WebJobs.Script.WebHost.csproj#L52).

Another is the Azure WebJobs SDK, the framework that simplifies the task of writing code to run on Azure Function runtime. We can use `HttpResult` and `IActionResult` because the SDK references [ASP.NET(Core) packages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/WebJobs.Extensions.Http.csproj#L25).

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" Version="5.2.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.1.0" />  
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="2.1.0" />
```

And our Function project can target at `netcoreapp2.1` or `netstandard2.0`. To consume .Net Core APIs, use `netcoreapp2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/686#issuecomment-389699549 Azure Functions does not support the notion of frameworks, but of the .NET Standard interface.

Your function has to target .NET Standard 2.0 which is implemented by dotnet core 2.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

See also https://github.com/dotnet/standard/milestone/3 - .NET Standard 2.1 is not available or close to be released yet.